# How to match values using excel Marcos in different workbooks?

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-formula

So I have two workbooks. One is called ADUsers.xls and the other one is DeviceInventory.xls

**ADUsers.xls** -
It has different columns one of which is userID (e2 to e565) and last one is match found (g2 to g565).

**DeviceInventory.xls** -
It has different columns but the one we need is userID (a3 - a3199).

**Problem** -
What we need to do is to one by one check the userID from ADUsers excel sheet and check the same against the userID column in DeviceInventory excel sheet. If the match is found somewhere in any of the 3199 rows, I want to insert "MATCH FOUND" in the corresponding row of ADUsers.xls in the column G.

Any idea how can I achieve this using excel macros ? Suggestions on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You don't need a macro for that... `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH(....),"MATCH FOUND","")`.

Comment: Which workbook will contain the code?

Comment: @VBasic2008 ADUSers.xls will contain the code

Comment: @BigBen These are two different workbooks. Can I still use this ? Sorry I'm new to all this

Comment: Absolutely, you can use a formula in one workbook referencing cell(s) in another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Find Matches

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub matchUsers()
    
    ' Adjust the following constants
    Const sFilePath As String = "C:\Test\DeviceInventory.xls"
    Const sName As String = "Sheet1"
    Const dName As String = "Sheet1"
    
    Dim srg As Range
    Set srg = Workbooks.Open(FilePath).Worksheets(sName).Range("A3:A3199")
    
    Dim drg As Range: Set drg = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(dName).Range("E2:E565")
        
    Dim dCell As Range
    For Each dCell In drg.Cells
        If IsNumeric(Application.Match(dCell.Value, srg, 0)) Then
            dCell.Offset(, 2).Value = "MATCH FOUND"
        End If
    Next dCell
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Okay. SO it says - Subscript out of range. Any idea what it is about? Actually I've applied some filter in the column A and hence the values are not consecutive..like A3 then A4 then A8 then A19..Do you think this is causing this issue ?

Comment: I don't think so. Which line is throwing the error? Have you adjusted the worksheet names and the source workbook path? The worksheet tab name may not be `Sheet1` and the workbook may not be located in the folder `C:\Test`.

Comment: Set srg = Workbooks.Open(sFilePath).Worksheets(sName).Range("A3:A3199") - This line